# How to assign role to a new user in bootstrap with grails spring security?

Tags: grails, spring-security, role

In my grails app i am using spring security plugin..I have registration form and registered users will be stored in db table.

in bootstrap i have created new role as,
 **def PhysicianRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_PHYSICIAN').save(flush: true)**

Then i have another form where admin is enabling or disabling users from table.

now i want to assign physician role to all the users who are enabled.so i did as below in bootstrap,
 **def physicians=Physician.findAllWhere(enabled:true)** with this i am getting array list as,

> physicians-------------->[com.HospitalManagement.User : 1, com.HospitalManagement.User : 2, com.HospitalManagement.User : 4, com.HospitalManagement.User : 5, com.HospitalManagement.User : 6, com.HospitalManagement.User : 7]

now how should i assign physician role to all the objects in this array list?

Comment: Please go through the syntax's that are to be followed when asking a question to improve readability.

Answer (score 1):

```
def physicianRole = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_PHYSICIAN')

for (physician in Physician.findAllWhere(enabled:true)) {
   if (!PhysicianRole.findByPhysicianAndRole(physician, physicianRole)) {
      PhysicianRole.create physician, physicianRole 
   }
}
```

Comment: With this i am getting error as**ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Cannot invoke method findByPhysicianAndRole() on null object**

Comment: You're missing an import for the PhysicianRole class.